# Notes client search without read capability: can I display "exists but you've not right to read"

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I need to check (in notes client preferably in lotuscript) if a document exists, but I'm not in readers field.

```
Set Doc = view.getdocumentbykey(index)   'returned Doc is nothing
```

I remember that in old version of Notes, I was getting a doc with items  property of the doc being nothing (thus no way to see item values which is logic if I've not right to see this doc). Is there a way to get this functionality?

If not, what is the best?

1. evaluate a DBLookUp on a categorized view (if still possible to do this when "don't show empty categories is **not** checked...)
2. execute a agent that run on behalf of (the signer will have right to read all docs) and will only return if doc exist or not for index (via environment notes.ini)
3. run on server an agent (with the heavy data exchange in a temp doc)
4. json from Notes Client

any other idea?

added to the questions some tries...

```
Dim key As String
key = Inputbox("index to search", "" , "123456")
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim view As NotesView
Dim nav As NotesViewNavigator
Dim entry As NotesViewEntry
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set view = db.GetView("ForSearch")
Set nav = view.CreateViewNavFromCategory(key )
If nav Is Nothing Then 
    MsgBox " nothing for "+ key

Else
    MsgBox " nav for " + key +": " & nav.Count 

    Set entry = nav.Getfirst()

    If entry Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "unable to get entry" 

        Dim vc As NotesViewEntryCollection
        Set vc = view.GetAllEntriesByKey(key, False)
        If vc Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "unable to getallentries for " + key
        Else
            MsgBox " vc exists for " + key + " count = " & vc.Count
            Set entry = vc.Getfirstentry()
            If entry Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "unable to get entry"
            Else
                MsgBox "entry: " & entry.Columnvalues(1)
            End if

            End If
        Else
            MessageBox "Universal ID: " & entry.UniversalID
        End If
    End If
```

problem: unable to get the entry in all the case! thus I can't identify if the index exists OR not... NB I see the category in notes client.

back to @dblookup:

```
t:=@DbLookup("":"";"":""; "forSearch" ; "123455" ; 2);

@Prompt([ok] ; "123456" ; @If(@IsError(t) ; "ERR:" ; "") + @Text(t) );
```

This will always return an error thus can't be used to test if the index exits...

```
t:= @DbColumn("":"" ; "":""; "forSearch" ; 1);
@Prompt([ok] ; "dbcolumn" ; @If(@IsError(t) ; "ERR:"  + @Text(t) ; @Contains(t; "123456") ; " @contains is true yep!" ;  " inexting index"));
```

yes now I remember this hack is only valid for @dbcolumn and his 64K limit :-(

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/DateAllFlatWeb/4af0288d37df3ade85257c3700779a0e?OpenDocument explains that in Notes client run on behalf could be tricky (http://www.ns-tech.com/blog/geldred.nsf/plinks/geld-7wmjev very nice article) so... a solution is to @formula cascading 3 @Command([ToolsRunMacro];"") or runonserver...

In my specific case this code is triggered by a JS timer, and I'm not sure calling a cascading 3 @command would be a good idea (meaning re writing a part of the code in formula to @return(false) when the condition are not validated ...) I will have to to this server side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 8.5.2 there is a possibility to run an agent with an in- memory document. The Method is called `NotesAgent.RunWithDocumentContext(doc As NotesDocument, noteID As String) As Integer`.
You can read more about it in [Daniel Nashed's Blog](http://blog.nashcom.de/nashcomblog.nsf/dx/passing-a-document-to-an-agent-without-saving-it-first.htm)

That -in combination with RunOnBehalf- would be my preferred way to do this.

Some clarifications: For that approach you always need TWO Agents / Script- Parts:

The first "Code" runs in User context and can be written in LotusScript / XPage JavaScript or Java. It creates the "in memory" document and then calls the other agent. That one has the property: "Run on behalf of" set. The SIGNER of that agent needs to have the right to run on behalf. Typically I set that agent to "Scheduled - Never"

Example code would look like this:

```
Dim ses as New NotesSession
Dim db as NotesDatabase
Dim docCache as NotesDocument
Dim ag as NotesAgent

Set db = ses.CurrentDatabase
Set docCache = New NotesDocument ( db )
'- set whatever parameters you want to transmit to the agent
Call docCache.ReplaceItemValue( "MyFirstParameter" , "something" )
Set ag = db.GetAgent( "AgentWithRonOnBehalf" )
Call ag.RunWithDocumentContext( docCache, "" )
'- read return parameter
docExists = docCache.GetItemValue( "docExists" )(0)
```

And in the AgentWithRunOnBehalf

```
Dim ses as New NotesSession
Dim docCache as NotesDocument

Set docCache = ses.DocumentContext
'- read parameters
myParameterValue = docCache.GetItemValue( "MyFirstParameter" )(0)
'- do your search / whatever
....
'- return the result to the calling code
Call docCache.ReplaceItemValue( "docExists", True )
```

Comment: I never succeeded to run ON LOCAL CLIENT **with** RunOnBehalf. Using runOnServer it works (I mean the agent run with the right of the runOnBehalf, I check this also with Effectiveusername). Consequently, I can't use the in memory document (No way the in memory would be shared between the client and the server). In this case, this cool 8.5.2 improvement is out of scope. If you successfully ran agent RunWithDocumentContext (which is local) with SIGNER privilege I would be happy to understand how you did this.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be where you could create a schedule' agent with the code snippet in your question. Sign the agent with Administrator's ID (or any ID which has access to all the documents in the database). If the document is found it can send you an email notification or it can create document (on which you have reader access) with the details of the document it found.

Comment: I updated the question, the difficulty is to launch the agent from the notes client WITH the signer/on behalf privileges.

Comment: I meant using a 'scheduled' agent which would run on server. I have updated my answer to reflect the same. Also, if your name is not in the 'readers' field then you cannot see the document. If you cannot see the document then you cannot look it up, even via code. If you can then it would be a serious security issue.

Comment: "serious security issue": you're right, in previous version of domino I remember it was possible to DBlookup the category. I re-discovered that this "HACK/serious security issue" is only valid for dbColumn on the category column.